# The size of the Java byte type is two bytes? In Why EMA (Eclipse Memory Analyzer) Does one byte is represented by 24 Shallow heap?

Tags: java, memory, char

The size of the Java byte type is two bytes? In Why EMA (Eclipse Memory Analyzer) Does one byte is represented by 24 Shallow heap?

And why char[1000] Shallow Retained Heap 2,040.

Comment: A "byte" in Java is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.  SUGGESTION: examine a Java class file with a disassembler.  I like [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/).

Comment: According with the Java Language Specification, one `char` occupies 16 bits. So, `char[1000]` shall occupy 2*1000 bytes +  some overhead.

Comment: @LittleSanti thank you comment